# Send message(Not SMS) from phone to phone

Tags: android

I need to send messages from phone to phone(Something like chat but with one direction) without requires from user to do registration(I want to use the phone number instead like Whatsapp), I searched everywhere all what I found is Google Cloud Messaging which works based on users registration not based on their phone numbers, anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: If you want to send message to phones in local network, you can use NSD to achieve this. Refer to the Link

The Sample App is a simple Chat app .This will give you an idea.

Comment: Do you want to know how to identify the device or how to send the data?

Comment: Not local network but over the internet.

Comment: felixd, I want to do that from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phones communicate using the radio for phone calls, SMS and data communication (you also have bluetooth and NFC, but those are probably not helpful for you).

To message another phone NOT using SMS, you only have data services as an option. Whatsapp and other companies use both data services (servers on the internet) and "gateways" to transfer SMS like messages from phone to phone. In other words, a gateway is a server connected to the phone network and can convert SMS to data messages and vice versa (for a fee).

Using data services only (like Google Cloud) is possible if you set up the services and device identifiers (i.e. phone numbers) necessary for communication. But then a few problems arise. First, your app has to be on any phone that wants to use your services. Google has "Google Play" - it's on most devices, but that's why GCM doesn't work on phones that don't have Google Play. Next, you have to build servers to handle the messaging (upload and download are pretty easy - but what about queuing when phones are out of network or off? how often do you poll? what happens if someone gets a new device? etc.) Amazon claims that AWS will do messaging to any Google device, but I haven't been able to get it to work (I think they have a back-end connection to GCM, but their support didn't provide much direction.)

Whatsapp uses gateways to move messages from data to devices where the other user does not have Whatsapp on the phone - and they pay a fee and the other user gets a real SMS. GCM is all data services, but nearly all devices have their app.

If you search, you will find a lot of references for gateways and service providers. You can also look up GCM and building a client will tell you a lot about how a server would be built. But it's not easy to say the least. Definitely not cheap.

Comment: Of course my app. will be installed on both sides.

Comment: Then you can use HTTP and a web server to send messages on a basic level. HTTPClient is easy to implement. Server side you just have to worry about serving pages with dynamic content and submitting GET/PUT data with a database of messages (like MySQL). Building a "real" system is tough (like Whatsapp) but that will get you a basic system.

Comment: And then there's polling or PUSHing notifications ... here's something on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024872/push-notification-from-device-to-device-over-local-network-without-c2dm?rq=1